# mongodb: update embedded array of objects with new array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Schema example:

```
_id: ObjectId
list: [{field: String}]
```

If I want to add an array of objects into list - how can I do that?
E.g. I have document like here:

```
{
  _id: 1
  list: [
    {field: "value1"}, {field: "value2"}
  ]
}
```

And I want to add into the list this array:

```
[{field: "val3"}, {field: "val4"}, {field: "val5"}]
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is there anything that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$push` operator together with `$each` to add all the items to an array in MongoDB:

```
db.collection.update({_id: 1}, { $push: { list: { $each: [{field: "val3"}, {field: "val4"}, {field: "val5"}]}}});
```

Answer (score 0):

To add objects into the array, you can use `push` function

```
var newFields  = [{field: "val3"}, {field: "val4"}, {field: "val5"}];
list.push(newFields);
```